# Replace the string

Tags: python

I'm working on my python script to add the numbers in the variable `program_top`.

I have the returns strings `315.0` which I want to replace it to `315`.

When I use this:

```
program_top = 315 + 37.5 * idx
```

Here is the results:

```
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315.0
```

I want to make the results like this:

```
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
20:48:02 T:3876  NOTICE: 315
```

Can you please tell me how I can use `program_top = 315 + 37.5 * idx` to remove the `.0` to replace it with empty string?

Comment: `int(315 + 37.5 * idx)`?

Comment: @g.d.d.c it sound like a good idea, but the string `352.5` will be replaced to `352` so i dont want the string of `352.5` to be replace as only for `.0`. how i can use the string.replace function to replace the string i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `program_top = int(315 + 37.5 * idx)`. This converts the float to an integer, so there will be no decimal places. If you only want to remove the decimal places if it ends with `.0`, try:

```
program_top = 315 + 37.5 * idx
if not program_top % 1.0:
    program_top = int(program_top)
```

String method:

```
program_top = str(315 + 37.5 * idx)
program_top = program_top[:-2] if program_top.endswith(".0") else program_top
```

However, the number based solution (above) is better.

Comment: thank you very much, but i still need the `.5` as i dont want to replace it to empty string as only for `.0`. any idea how i can use `program_top = 315 + 37.5 * idx` to replace the strings `.0` to empty string?

Comment: it has got nothing to do with version. i have the list of strings `315.0`, `390.0` so i want to replace `.0` to empty strings. how i can do that using string.replace function?